# Statistical physics Susskind lecture question? Proof of Boltzmann distribution

Tags: statistical-mechanics, statistics

In lecture 3 of the following series by Susskind on statistical physics, at 36 minutes in he takes the following [step](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SmmGDn8OnTA&t=35m59s) and spends the next 5 minutes discussing it, 
\begin{equation}
f(P_i)=-N\sum _iP_i\log P_i-\alpha \big[\sum _iP_i-1\big]-\beta \big[\sum _iE_iP_i-\langle E\rangle\big]
\end{equation}
To,
\begin{equation}
f(P_i)=-\sum _iP_i\log P_i-\alpha \big[\sum _iP_i-1\big]-\beta \big[\sum _iE_iP_i-\langle E\rangle\big]
\end{equation}
That is to say, in his derivation of the [Boltzmann distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boltzmann_distribution) he cancels the $N$ (total number of states) from his calculation.

This mathematically makes sense since the stationary point of a function is equal to the stationary point of an integer times that function, however physically we have gone from discussing the total [entropy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entropy) of the system to the entropy of the $i$th state.

Is this step appropriate to those with experience in this area? Personally I am reluctant to throw away constants so easily and it makes me a little uneasy about this derivation. That being said I think the lectures are a fantastic source for introductions or refreshers to statistical physics!

Comment: Perhaps you could link to the time when he makes the derivation.  The video is 2 hours.

Comment: @Mew Linked to about 30s before problem so you are familiar with the set up :)

Comment: Pretty sure you can drop the $N$ because you're just trying to find the $P_i$ that maximizes $f$, and dropping $N$ has no effect. Further, when deriving the Boltzmann distribution, you end up with something *proportional* to $e^{-\beta E}$. The constants out front don't matter, since the normalization will be taken care of by the partition function. He even drops the term with the $\alpha$ Lagrange multiplier, because it, like $N$, is just a constant.